# Retrieving and using partial results from Pool

Tags: file-io, multiprocessing

I have three functions that read, process and write respectively. Each function was optimized (to the best of my knowledge) to work independently. Now, I am trying to pass each result of each function the next one in the chain as soon as it is available instead of waiting for the entire list. I am not really sure how I can connect them. Here's what I have so far.

```
def main(files_to_load):
    loaded_files = load(files_to_load)
    with ThreadPool(processes=cpu_count()) as pool:
        proccessed_files = pool.map_async(processing_function_with_Pool, iterable=loaded_files).get()
    write(proccessed_files)
```

As you can see, my main() function waits for all the files to load (about 500Mb) stores them to memory and sends them to processing_function_with_Pool() which divides the files into chunks to be processed.After all the processing is done, the files will start to be written to disk. I feel like there's a lot of unnecessary waiting between these three steps. How can I connect everything?

Answer (score 0):

Now your logic is reading all the files sequentially (I guess) and storing them at once in memory.

I'd recommend you to send to `processing_function_with_Pool` just a list with the file names to be processed.

The `processing_function_with_Pool` will take care of reading, processing the file and writing the results back.

In this way you'll take advantage of dealing with IO concurrently.

If the `processing_function_with_Pool` is doing CPU-bound work, I'd suggest you to switch to a Pool of processes.